# Higher performance on Remote Desktop than local console?

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, remote-desktop

I often use my notebook via RDP over a fast local network. I also use my notebook locally (so not over RDP). When over RDP, I notice that there is never a delay when switching windows and such. When using it over the console, switching windows regularly lag a bit (not much but enough to notice it).

I guess this has something to do with some useless graphic parts being shut down over RDP. Any idea how I get my notebook in the same performance mode as I am over RDP?

Notebook specs are fine also:

- Windows 10 (upgraded from 7)
- 16 GB RAM
- Intel Core i7
- NVIDIA K2100M

Answer (score 0):

The following screenshot shows the experience factors of Remote Desktop:

[image]

You try enabling and disabling them in *System Properties*. To get there:

1. Right-click on *This PC* icon.
2. Select *Properties*.
3. From the left, on the task pane, select *Advanced system settings*.
4. From the *Performance* section, click on *Settings...* button.

Comment: All checkboxes are unchecked so I guess it's already maxed @ performance?

Comment: I am out of ideas. And you have K2200 too. You should feel no lags...

Comment: Correction K2100M :)

Comment: Huh! That's a bit disappointing. It is like a demotion from CEO to a CEO's mistress. In that case, if the computer from which you connect has a better graphic card that supports RemoteFX, that's the reason.

Comment: The PC from which I connect doesn't have a better graphic card